# При попытке обновления получаю "No new release found"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, update

Решил обновиться до 16 версии ОС и нашел в интернете информацию о том что обновится на прямую нельзя.
То есть сначала нужно обновиться до 15.10 и только за тем до 16.04
Но я столкнулся с проблемой, я не могу обновить ОС до версии 15.10
При попытке обновления появляется сообщение с текстом "No new release found"

```
do-release-upgrade -d
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found
```

Comment: А у Вас в списке репозитариев присутствует репозитарий, содержащий 15.10 ?

Comment: @Sergey Как он должен выглядеть ?

Comment: Текущий релиз какой?

Comment: @T1MOXA Для того, что бы посмотреть список подключённых репозитариев, необходимо выполнить команду *cat /etc/apt/sources.list* Это в Ubuntu. Для других дистрибутуивов может быть несколько иначе. В любом случае, для того, что бы перейти на другой дистрибутив, нужно репозитарий этого дистрибутива внести в *sources.list*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил эту проблему следующим образом:

```
sudo sed -i 's/vivid/wily/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
Эта команда заменяет в репозиториях слово vivid на wily
```

И за тем уже спокойно обновляюсь до последней версии

P.S. Спасибо за помощь @Sergio Lione, @Sergey

Answer (score -2):

Наверное (уверен на 80%) надо обновить в sources.list правильный репозиторий...

help.ubuntu.ru => [Документация.Репозиторий](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9)

Comment: Как это сделать ?

Comment: @SergioLione, пожалуйста, делайте по возможности более развёрнутые ответы. Данный ответ тянет на комментарий (который будут доступны при достижении репутации >= 50).

Comment: @T1MOXA **Как это сделать ?** Можно в любом текстовом редакторе (с правами root) отредактировать файл *sources.list*, Можно в графическом интерфейсе: "Параметры системы / Программы и обновления / Другое ПО